# Adding multiple values to a unique key in dictionary - Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary, key-value

The following is a sample dataset obtained from the CSV file.

```
7493928 O88643  P60953
7493922 O88643  P60954
749392e O88643  P65657 
7493923 O88643  P65656
5845930 YPL094C YPR086W
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary in python using the sample1 column as the key and sample2 as it's values. I want some guidance over here to create a dictionary in the following format where it doesn't repeat the keys (sample1) and concatenates multiple values (sample2) to the same key.

```
'O88643': ['P60953', 'P60954', 'P65657', 'P65656'], 'YPL094C': ['YPR086W']
```

Any input on this will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). I don't know exactly how you're processing your data, but you would use it something like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

samples = defaultdict(list)
for row in csv_rows:
    row_id, sample1, sample2 = row
    samples[sample1].append(sample2)
```

A `defaultdict` will create a new item if one isn't found when you go to look up a key. So when you encounter the first item (`O88643`), the `samples` defaultdict will create a new `list` for that key. Then you can immediately append the `sample2` value to that list.

Comment: Thank you for this example and this solved my issue.